# creating forms in zend with ini file

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I know Zend_Form gets a lot of hate from many developers, I've even heard that for many it was the main turn-off to switching from [insert random php framework name here] to ZF, but just a little time ago I found out that creating forms with an .ini file is the way around this and the best way of doing it. I haven't found any useful info googling around it, can anyone point me the right path to it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A .ini file could be anything. It's just a generic term for configuration files. Kind of like saying "I saw a car on the road. What brand was it?". Without more details, I doubt you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Create the ini file eg. (we will use forms.ini for this example)

[production]

```
user.login.elements.LastName.type = "text"
user.login.elements.LastName.options.label = "Last Name:"
```

(save it to ../configs/forms.ini)

In the bootstrap you need to intialize it, something like this:

```
  $forms = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/forms.ini', 'production');
  Zend_Registry::set('forms', $forms);
```

then in your controller you call it

```
        $forms = Zend_Registry::get('forms');
        $form = new Zend_Form($forms->user->login);
        $this->view->form = $form;
```

and on your view you would display it by using either

```
<?php echo $this->form ;?>
```

or if you were trying to access just one form element from the login set you would do something like this

```
<?php echo $this->form->LastName ;?>
```

hope this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. It's stated in the official manual at this page: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.quickstart.html

Scroll down to the section called "Using a Zend_Config Object". There you got some examples.

As mentioned in the doc, the Zend_Config factory will ingest the .ini file describing your form. After that, you can build a Zend_Form using that Zend_Config instance.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini($configFile, 'development');
$form   = new Zend_Form($config->user->login);
```

Comment: sure it will. Thanks a lot faileN